# Scraping all the images from a specific part of a webpage using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Object 'gallery' is what I got - how would I be able to just select the image urls without going a long way around.

Currently, I am doing the following

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PIL import Image
import requests


gallery = soup.findAll(class_='gallery')
img_0 = gallery[0].find('img')
img_1 = gallery[1].find('img')
...
img_x = gallery[x].find('img')

img_url_0 = img_0['src']
img_url_1 = img_1['src']
...
img_url_x = img_x['src']

gallery_img_0 = Image.open(requests.get(img_url_0, stream = True).raw)
gallery_img_1 = Image.open(requests.get(img_url_1, stream = True).raw)
...
gallery_img_x = Image.open(requests.get(img_url_x, stream = True).raw)
```

where x is the length of the gallery iterable.

Perhaps a loop? :s

Thanks, CN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested loop to load all image and store them to a list. For example:

```
galleries = soup.findAll(class_='gallery')

all_images = []
for gallery in galleries:
    for img in gallery.findAll('img'):
        gallery_img = Image.open(requests.get(img['src'], stream = True).raw)
        all_images.append(gallery_img)

# here, `all_images` contains all images
# ...
```